# Custom exception message using JUnit assertEquals?

Tags: java, testing, junit, customization

I'm using assert equals to compare two numbers

```
Assert.assertEquals("My error message", First , Second);
```

Then, when I generate the Test Report I get

> "My error message *expected* (First) *was* (Second)"

How can I customize the part I've put in italic? And the format of the numbers?

Comment: I've assumed you're using Java. If it's Scala, please adjust the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like this:

```
int a=1, b=2;
String str = "Failure: I was expecting %d to be equal to %d";
assertTrue(String.format(str, a, b), a == b);
```

Comment: This will not improve the situation. The OP already knows how to add an error message, but the goal is to change the wording of the part in italics. Your solution will still have the wording in place.

Comment: Are you sure? Running on Eclipse with (2,1) I only get "Failure: I was expecting 2 to be equal to 1" and not the "expected... was" part...

Comment: @Salem that's because you're using assertTrue, not assertEquals

Answer (score 7):

The message is hard-coded in the `Assert` class. You will have to write your own code to produce a custom message:

```
if (!first.equals(second)) {
  throw new AssertionFailedError(
      String.format("bespoke message here", first, second));
}
```

(Note: the above is a rough example - you'll want to check for nulls etc. See the code of `Assert.java` to see how it's done).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answer I've found in the Assert class this

```
        static String format(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    String formatted= "";
    if (message != null && !message.equals(""))
        formatted= message + " ";
    String expectedString= String.valueOf(expected);
    String actualString= String.valueOf(actual);
    if (expectedString.equals(actualString))
        return formatted + "expected: "
                + formatClassAndValue(expected, expectedString)
                + " but was: " + formatClassAndValue(actual, actualString);
    else
        return formatted + "expected:<" + expectedString + "> but was:<"
                + actualString + ">";
}
```

I guess I can't modify Junit Assert class, but I can create a new class in my project with the same name, just changing format, am I right? Or I can just change format in my class and it will affect the Exception thrown?

Comment: Yes, you can take this approach. This is essentially what I'm suggesting in my answer - you'll have to write your own code to do the test if you need to change the message.